# Could not connect to SQL Server instance from one of the machines

Tags: sql-server, windows

I have two machines (a laptop and a desktop) connected to the same network throgh the same router and an SQL Server with 2 instances: *ODD* and *EVEN*, both instances have the same configuration (as far as I can see), including sa account settings.

From my desktop I can connect to both instances, but from laptop I can connect only to the *EVEN* instance, when I try to connect to *ODD* instance I get the following error:

> ---
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> ---
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> ---
>
> OK
>
> ---

I know that:

1. I have correct password, because I can connect to *EVEN*
2. I have correct firewall settings, because I can connect to *EVEN* and both instances use the same TCP/IP port 1433
3. I have properly configures server, because I can connect to the both instances from desktop.

How should I troubleshoot this issue? Is there any more detailed information about what went wrong? Why does Visual Studio uses named pipes and does not try TCP/IP for example?

Comment: you mean that you have a server computer too or your desktop act as a server?

Comment: server (where SQL Server is installed) is a network virtual machine in on-premise cloud

Comment: have you tried to disable Name Pipes protocol on your laptop?

Comment: I am not sure I can disable Named Pipes *on client*. But I have found that using `tcp:<ip address>\ODD` I get the the same error with different provider: *provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 28 - Server doesn't support requested protocol*

Answer (score 0):

Check Sql Server Configuration manager on your client and server to see if TCP/IP protocol is enable or not. you can even disable Named Pipes protocol there and see how it will effect on VS error message.
you can even check server setting by trying below command from command shell.

```
telnet server-ip 1433
```

Comment: I do not have any SQL Components (like `SQL Server` or `SQL Server Configuration Manager` installed on my clients), but in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cliconfg.exe` and `C:\Windows\System32\cliconfg.exe` on General tab both Named Pipes and TCP/IP were in *Disabled protocols* list. But one of the instances still worked with those settings. After I moved both protocols to *Enabled protocols* list and restarted Visual Studio - the error is still present

Comment: It seems you are correct about server settings, I could not connect via TCP to that instance from both my machines, I will investigate this further

Comment: @DarkWalker run mmc and from its file menu select add/remove snap-ins and look if you see Sql Server Configuration Manager

Comment: no I do not have `Sql Server Configuration Manager` in there

Comment: @DarkWalker how about your desktop computer it dose not have too?

Comment: yes, both of them lack the Configuration Manager... Btw I have found that I can not telnet into SQL Server despite port 1433 being used in both `SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration (32 bit)` and `SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration`  as Default Port. I even tried to put port 1433 in `SQL Server Network Configuration` into `IP Addresses` tab, but this did not help - I still get failed connection in telnet. I have even turned off firewalls on all machines (laptop, desktop, server)

Comment: The problem is still local to ODD instance, I can easily connect to EVEN using `tcp:<ip address>/EVEN`